# Time complexity of the merge sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, math, time-complexity, big-o

[image]

My Doubt is that I don't understand which property or how they take common in line no. 3

Can someone please explain in simple language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess maybe it would be simpler than that:

- `n` numbers can be sorted in `n log n` of time.
- The question is how many numbers can be sorted in `n` of time.

---

It would be then as simple as:

[image]

Comment: Your method happens to get the right result, but it assumes n log n scales linearly with n (which it doesn't). If you use your method for an O(n^2) algorithm, you get n/X = n^2/n => X = 1 (rather than the correct X = sqrt(n)).

Answer (score 1):

It's just by definition of the big-O notation: O(log n - loglog n)=O(log n)
(In fact it should be big-Theta here).

Comment: Sir In 3rd line after O(n/logn log (n/logn)).

Comment: The second part in the 3rd line is just explanation, not a part of expresssion

Answer (score 1):

It's not about taking common, in **"[longn - loglogn = O(logn)]"** they actually explained the logic, this portion is separate from the original expression.

I think they tried to write in this way, **"[O(logn - loglogn) = O(logn)]"**